# Display the name of the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need help please, There is something I haven't understood yet.
I want to display the name of the user who has posted the "tuto"...

Here is the tutos/index.html.slim
I must be wrong around here, or I am missing something  elsewhere...
Anyone could explain please ? Thanks a lot

```
- @tutos.each do |tuto|
  .row
    .col-xs-4
      h6 = link_to tuto.title, tuto_path(tuto)
    .col-xs-4
      h6 = tuto.user.full_name
```

Here is my users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def show
      @user = User.find(current_user)
  end

  def index
    @user = User.all
  end

  #def full_name
    #first_name + last_name
  #end
  # Edited put this in the user model
  
  private
  def params_user
    params.require(:users).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :id)
  end
end
```

Here is the tutos controller:

```
class TutosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  #as suggested I added the line above
  before_action :set_tuto, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    @tutos = Tuto.all
  end

  def show
    @tuto = Tuto.find(params[:id])
  end


 def new
    @tuto = Tuto.new
    # as suggested I added the line below
    @user = current_user
  end


  def edit
  end

  def create
    @tuto = Tuto.new(tuto_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tuto.save
        format.html { redirect_to @tuto, notice: 'Tuto was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tuto }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @tuto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tuto.update(tuto_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @tuto, notice: 'Tuto was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @tuto }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @tuto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @tuto.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tutos_url, notice: 'Tuto was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_tuto
      @tuto = Tuto.find(params[:id])
    end

    def tuto_params
      params.require(:tuto).permit(:title, :content, :id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

the schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160916141853) do

  create_table "tutos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "tutos", ["user_id"], name: "index_tutos_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.boolean  "admin"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

tuto model :

```
class Tuto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

end
```

user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name,  presence: true
  has_many :tutos
  
  # moved this from the controller users (as suggested)
  def full_name
    first_name + last_name
  end


end
```

and if needed my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  namespace :admin do
    get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/'
    resources :tutos
    resources :users
    resources :dashboard
  end

  namespace :users do
    resources :tutos
  end

as :user do
  get '/register', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :register
  get '/login',    to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :login
  get '/logout',   to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
end

devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions]

as :user do
  get     "/account"  => "users#show", as: :account
  get     "/login"    => "devise/sessions#new", as: :new_user_session
  post    "/login"    => "devise/sessions#create", as: :user_session
  delete  "/logout"   => "devise/sessions#destroy", as: :destroy_user_session
end

  resources :users
  resources :tutos

  root "home#landing"
```

end

## EDIT:

As suggested I added:

in tutos_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @tuto = Tuto.new
  end
```

hidden_field in my form like this:

```
= simple_form_for @tuto do |f|
  - if @tuto.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      h2 = "#{pluralize(@tuto.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this tuto from being saved:"
      ul
        - @tuto.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          li = message
  = hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id
  = f.input  :title
  = f.input  :content    
  = f.button :submit, "Save"
```

but I have now this error : `undefined method id' for nil:NilClass`
the user_id is nil all the time when I create a tuto....

Please I need more help :)

## EDIT (again)

I have something strange...
I tried to debug with pry and I have this :
*in the tutos_controller*

```
  22: def create
 => 23:   binding.pry
    24:
    25:   @tuto = Tuto.new(tuto_params)
    26:
    27:   respond_to do |format|
    28:     if @tuto.save
    29:       format.html { redirect_to @tuto, notice: 'Tuto was successfully created.' }
    30:       format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tuto }
    31:     else
    32:       format.html { render :new }
    33:       format.json { render json: @tuto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    34:     end
    35:   end
    36: end

[1] pry(#<TutosController>)>
[1] pry(#<TutosController>)> params
=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"SkY9I70/ng+fwQr7HJ1oYzpKPI/kRnEsHxukIrAQ/kA+VOrS7TpXL0Ab6BW3O13sLZyrRWJpOxANLVIE/2wGVw==",
 "user_id"=>"1",
 "tuto"=>{"title"=>"A title", "content"=>"Some text"},
 "commit"=>"Save",
 "controller"=>"tutos",
 "action"=>"create"}
```

So I can notice that the `user_id: 1`

### BUT

In my console when I search for the tuto:

```
  Tuto Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tutos".* FROM "tutos"  ORDER BY "tutos"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Tuto id: 16, created_at: "2016-09-17 08:59:09", updated_at: "2016-09-17 08:59:09", title: "A title", content: "Some text", user_id: nil>
2.3.1 :006 >
```

user_id is nil....

Comment: Now the thing is that you are probably not calling the callback authenticate_user! from devise, i updated my answer

Comment: You can go two ways change **hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id** to **hidden_field_tag :tuto_user_id, current_user.id** and it will appear on your tuto params method since it will be filtered on the permit part, or you can add the user_id to your params, in the controller instead of this ***@tuto = Tuto.new(tuto_params)*** put ***Tuto.new(tuto_params.merge(user_id: params[:user_id]))***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, the method *full_name* is on the controller it needs to be on the model.

You see you are using it right, but you have a *tuto* object that references his *user* model and the full_name method is on a controller, so it is an action in the controller not an instance method of the user model, that is what you need.

Also, you have an **n+1** problem there, you need to include users on you query in the tutos controller:

```rb
def index
  @tutos = Tuto.all.includes(:user)
end
```

Otherwise, you will hit the database one more time with every tuto, every time you display the users name

To sum up, just move the **full_name** method from your controller **users_controller.rb** to your model **user.rb** also check the [n+1 problem](https://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/) and you are golden.

Ok now your problem is with the **devise** gem. First of all, **current_user** is a helper made available by [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) on the callback **authenticate_user!** this should be typically on your **application_controller.rb**, after that callback gets called you can access **current_user** among other helpers, so you don't need the instance variable **@user** because **current_user** will be available on the view as well, your problem seems to be that the callback is not being called properly, it should be at the top of your controllers hierarchy.

Comment: Good catch, didn't see that.

Comment: I need what you advised but it still doesn't work 
I notice in my console that :
`Tuto.all
  Tuto Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tutos".* FROM "tutos"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Tuto id: 1, created_at: "2016-09-16 15:37:02", updated_at: "2016-09-16 15:37:02", title: "OPOP", content: "ploc", user_id: nil>]>`
I think there is something wrong elsewhere too

Comment: did* not need... (sorry)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what `full_name` is.  You can write a method on the users.rb model file like this:

```
def full_name
  [last_name, first_name].join(", ")
end
```

For a user with `first_name` of "John" and `last_name` of "Smith", it will return "Smith, John".

EDIT
see the answer from @aledustet

Comment: Hi thanks for your fast answer , it says `undefined method full_name' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: If it says that, then the link from tuto to user is broken.  `tuto.user` => a user object.  If that's nil, then something is wrong.  What is `tuto.user_id`?

Comment: something is wrong I believe.... `tuto.user`gives undefined method user...
and I can see in the console that in` tuto: user_id: nil `

Comment: Make sure that your tuto objects are being created correctly.  In the controller, inspect the params.

Comment: Sorry If I sound nuts... how can I inspect, I tried with a `binding.pry`but I am not sure where to puts it...

Comment: put binding.pry in the first line of the create action - before `@tuto = Tuto.new(tuto_params)`

Comment: okay so that's what I did... and the result is weird `undefined method pry' for #<Binding:0x007fd6372180a8> Did you mean? try`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123575/discussion-between-johan-and-john-feltz).

Comment: @Johan, sorry.  I may be assuming too much.  Do you have a debugging gem installed?  How do you go about debugging your code - have you ever put in a break point so you could inspect data?

Comment: Inspect objects like this: `puts @tuto.inspect` and see it in logs if you are having difficulty while debugging.

Comment: I did a binding pry in the create method, when I am in there I have the user_id that appears , but in the console it doesn't see my edit please :)

Comment: Is user_id inside the tutu subhash in params?  If not, you need to add it manually before saving.

Answer (score 0):

try following. in `user.rb`

```
  def full_name
    if first_name.present? || last_name.present?
      "#{first_name} #{last_name}" 
    end
  end
```

Comment: that doesn't change anything sorry :(